# Shorten fraction line

Tags: fractions

I understand that this request may sound stupid, but my eyes are just bleeding when I see how `$\frac{x^-}{2}$` is rendered:

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a moderately simple way to make it look like this?

[image]

(Please do not suggest `$\frac{x^-}{2^{\phantom{-}}}$` or `$\frac{{}^{\phantom{-}}x^-}{2}$`.)

**UPDATE**

Well, OK, I've realized that `\frac{x}{2}^{-}` may work as a temporary solution, but now my eyes are bleeding when looking at the source code.

Comment: How about `\frac{x^{\mathmakebox[0pt][l]{-}}}{2}` with `mathtools`?

Comment: Cool, thanks. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: (Even though, it would be preferable to ensure that minus does not stay above the following symbols.)

Comment: Maybe the result of `\frac{x^{-}}{2}` is not that pretty, but the proposed layout is much worse to my eyes.

Comment: Not only your eyes are bleeding when you look at the code `$\frac{x}{2}^{-}$`, it gives undesired output in non-display mathmode, especially if the denominator is not a single character, as in  `$\frac{x}{222}^{-}$`.  Putting two `~` in front of `x` does a reasonable job, no matter what the denominator is, as in `$\displaystyle \frac{~~x^{-}}{2}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My eyes bleed with your proposal. Anyway

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fracto}[3]{%
  {\mathpalette\frac@to{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand{\frac@to}[2]{\frac@@to#1#2}
\newcommand{\frac@@to}[4]{%
  % #1 = mathstyle
  % #2 = full numerator
  % #3 = denominator
  % #4 = reduced numerator
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\frac{#2}{#3}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\frac{#4}{#3}$}%
  \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th\frac@to@demote#1#4$}%
  \frac{{}\makebox[\dimen@][l]{$\frac@to@demote#1#2$}}{#3}%
  \kern-\wd\tw@
  \kern\wd\z@
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\frac@to@demote[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
X + \frac{x^{-}}{2} + \frac{x^{-}}{100} + X \\
X + \fracto{x^{-}}{2}{x} + \fracto{x^{-}}{100}{x} + X \\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

First I typeset the standard fraction, then the same but with the “reduced numerator” in two boxes, so I can use their widths. I also measure the reduced numerator.

Then I typeset the fraction with the numerator having the same width as the reduced one (aligned left). This fraction is as wide as box 2, so I back up by this amount and reinstate the width of the standard fraction, which is the width of box 0.

Comment: Oh God, I will not even ask how this works.

Comment: @mavzolej Added short explanation.

Answer (score 11):

I'll be happy to remove this but you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{x^{\mathrlap{-}}}{2}\hphantom{\scriptstyle -}x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not bad! This is smth that can be easily generalised for more complicated cases.